# Windows 11 - Cannot access Shared Files

Tags: network-shares, windows-11

I just received a new computer with windows 11. I just want to share a folder but I've been struggling for the past 5 hours. I've check a lot of resources online but wasn't able to figure out what's wrong.

Here's the interesting things:

- If I disable/enable the network discovery, it works. I can see/unsee the computer in windows explorer, as expected.
- The remote desktop works flawlessly (nothing to have with the file sharing, but just to point out that I can connect with a user/pwd)
- From the folder properties, The share and security settings are set to full access for some users.

The error prompt I get is `\\MYCOMPUTER is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource...`.

I have checked a lot of things (services, users, groups, share settings, etc). Obviously, It's not the first time I do that (been doing that since win95) and for some reasons, I just can't figure out where to look in order to debug it. I've checked in the event logs, but I don't see any failed attempts, so I might not be looking at the right place. I have tried different users but with the same result. If i check on the server, I can list the share folder and open it without any issue (since it's the local user).

So if someone has any idea why it wouldn't work or how to debug it, that would be really appreciated.

---

Edit #1: It's a wired connection

Edit #2: Tests are done with a win10 client to a win 11 server.

Edit #3: It seems to work using the IP directly. Also disabled the IPv6 just to be sure.

Comment: If on Wireless make sure the connection is Private.  In addition to Network Discovery, turn ON File and Print sharing and Password protected sharing.  I have two Windows 11 Pro systems and file sharing is nice and easy.

Comment: It's not on wireless, the connection is private, file and print sharing is on. I even disabled the wifi network interface in my tests just to be sure.

Comment: Make sure the computer you are accessing is Windows 10 or higher. From the Windows 11 computer, File Explorer, left side down and browse the network. Make sure the computer you are accessing does not have SMB V1 enabled.

Comment: Is there such an option on windows (smb settings)?

Comment: Just found it here, will test later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3?tabs=server

Comment: Just make sure that all systems are SMB V2 up.

Comment: Both are disabled and still doesn't work: using this command: "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol".

Comment: I've also tried both enabled...

Comment: Be sure to disable SMBv1

Comment: Yep. that's what I did and when I run the command lines on both, it still says disabled. I've tried with a linux machine and still cannot connect. I've also tried disabling IPv6

Comment: Ok, I just tried using the IP directly and it works. So it might be a problem with the interface between netbios and the file sharing.